# WebDriver 2.45.0 & Firefox esr 31.5.0 :: WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms

Tags: selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I'm testing selenium remote webdriver with grid and I got stuck with an error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'XXXXX', ip: 'XXXXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
Command duration or timeout: 47.71 seconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'XXXXX', ip: 'XXXXX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
```

Info about my configuration:

- selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0
- browser: Firefox esr 31.5.0
- I run tests with eclipe and testNG
- Hub configuration:
  `{
    "host": null,
    "port": 4444,
    "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
    "servlets" : [],
    "prioritizer": null,
    "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
    "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
    "nodePolling": 5000,
    "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
    "timeout": 300000,
    "browserTimeout": 0,
    "maxSession": 100,
    "jettyMaxThreads":-1
  }`
- I have three nodes with configuration like this:

  `{
  "capabilities":
    [
      {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "maxInstances": 5,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      },
      {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "maxInstances": 5,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      },
      {
        "browserName": "iexplorer",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      }
    ],
  "configuration":
  {
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 10,
  "port": 5555,
  "host": ip,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hubPort": 4444,
  "hubHost": ip
  }
  }`

**My question is**: what could be the reasons for this error? 
For the moment I don't even understand why there is locking port 7054 even if my hub and nodes configuration ports are different.

Thanks for your time and answers.

**UPDATE:**

**@BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod functions**

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(){

    StringBuilder text = customAppender.createInstance();
    customAppender.setBuilder(text);    

    WebDriver driver = LocalDriverFactory.createInstance("firefox");
    LocalDriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);
    customAppender.append("Opened webDriver instance = " + driver.hashCode());
}

@AfterMethod
public void shutDown(){
    WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
    if (driver != null) {
        mainFunctions.log("Closed webDriver instance = " + driver.hashCode(), 2);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**@Test methods:**

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
public static void test(String browserName, String link) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
        customAppender.append("Thread id = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        customAppender.append("Hashcode of webDriver instance = " + driver.hashCode());
        driver.get(link);
        customAppender.append(driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(20000); // for testing purposes
        customAppender.append("Test 1, time: " + new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        mainFunctions.log(customAppender.printOutString(), 0);
    }

@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
public static void test2(String browserName, String link) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
        customAppender.append("Thread id = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        customAppender.append("Hashcode of webDriver instance = " + driver.hashCode());
        driver.get(link);
        customAppender.append(driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(20000); // for testing purposes
        customAppender.append("Test 2, time: " + new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        mainFunctions.log(customAppender.printOutString(), 0);
    }
```

**@DataProvider**

```
@DataProvider(parallel=true)
    public Object[][] getData(){
        Object[][] d = new Object[4][2];
        // dummy data

        d[0][0] = "firefox";
        d[0][1] = "http://www.google.com";

        d[1][0] = "firefox";
        d[1][1] = "http://www.google.com";

        d[2][0] = "firefox";
        d[2][1] = "http://www.google.com";

        d[3][0] = "firefox";
        d[3][1] = http://www.google.com";

        return d;
    }
```

**testNG.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="20"> 
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="ts.testWebdriver" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: just came back to this situation. Any other suggestions available? :)

Answer (score 1):

the cause might be that your firefox instance via webdriver is running on that particular port on remote machine. Kill the ff instance and execute the test. Do provide driver.quit() at end of your test case to avoid these failures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;)
I have driver.quit(); at the end of test case, but also there is  if clause: if (driver != null)
I will check if this could be possible problem. Also added more info to main post, to see what I'm doing here :)

Comment: Is `WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();` creating new driver instance? If so please have a look at shutDown method where u are trying to kill the new driver u got from line 1 of shutdown. Thanks.

Comment: No, `LocalDriverManager.getDriver();` is returning webdriver instance:    

`public class LocalDriverManager {
private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
 
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return webDriver.get();
    }  
 
    public static void setWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        webDriver.set(driver);
    }
}`    

  
  
Instance is created with `LocalDriverFactory.createInstance("firefox");`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've had this issue with WebDriver, but couldn't fix it.
Found a workaround though. 
I've created a new Windows user, and ran the tests from that user. Seems ok now. Good luck.

Comment: Just wondering how can it be related with windows users.. strange, thanks for suggestion :)